# check how many characters input had with fread function

Tags: c, fread

How can I check the amount of characters that were entered using the fread function in C.

```
char buffer[101]; 
int bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 100, stdin);
```

Inputting 100 chars results in the desired outcome. However inputting over 100 leads to fread just cutting the other chars so I could never see what the user actually typed. I know there are other ways which are not making use of fread but I actually have to use it here , so I can check the user input and in the case the input length was >100 I can give a error that the cache was exceeded.

Comment: It's not true that _inputting over 100 leads to fread just cutting the other chars_; they rather remain there waiting to be read.

Comment: well is there any way to access the length of the waiting chars ?

Comment: call fread again

Comment: But it seems you can just do `if(bytesRead > 100) { /* handle error */ }`.  Note that `fread` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.  But what do you mean by "user input"?  It is probably best to stop thinking of your input stream as "user input"; it is just "input".  In particular, what do you mean by "input length greater than 100"?  Are you looking for a newline character, or are you waiting for the input stream to be closed?

Comment: Well basically the user has to type in a string of length 100 . Lets say100 a's. With my implementation , inputting 99a's into the command line nothing happens. At 101 a's I would like to return an error. But what actually happens is that the function just give me the first 100a's and keeps going in the code whereas I would like to know at that point, alright the user typed in 101 a's . if(bytesRead > 100) doesnt work , I already had that but just to realize byteRead is always 100 , so it never goes in there

Comment: What do you want to happen on inputting 99a's into the command line? (When you say _inputting_, do you imply pressing the Enter key?)

Comment: 99 a was just an example . Yes we input a string of 100chars and press enter

Comment: You state that your program should print an error message if the user enters more than 100 characters before pressing ENTER. What should happen if the user enters less than 100 characters before pressing ENTER? Should the program print an error message in that case, too?

Comment: my task is basically: fread has to read the string until of the end of the file into a cache of size 100 .I guess file here means just the user input. I just assumed that the input has to be taken until 100 chars are read because fread doesnt stop before anyways or is there a way to stop the fread reading loop before 100 ? To your question, no there should be no error , just if the cache is too small for the input

Comment: @EzrealQ: Is the "file" a binary file or a text file? If it is a binary file, then there is a big difference between such a file and user input, because user input is generally text-based.

Comment: nono in the task the input is just a text based standard input , a string. Aim is to reformat the string according to the task , like removing \n etc but thats easy afterwards. I just dont know how to display this cache error

Comment: @EzrealQ: You could simply tell `fread` to read 101 characters and then (1) verify that all 101 characters were indeed read, and (2) verify that the 101th character is the newline character and that no other newline characters were entered. That way, you can be sure that the user entered exactly 100 characters before pressing ENTER. However, for the reasons described in my answer, this method will be unable to detect if the user entered less than 100 characters in the first line until the user actually enters 100 characters in total.

Comment: okok i got it I guess. Didnt know that pressing enter added \n to the end of the array. Thanks for your efforts. Idk if its 100% right this way because the user has to enter 100 characters as you said but I guess its the best way so far.

Comment: @EzrealQ: I have now changed the `fgets` solution in my answer so that if the input is too short, it will also reject the input and prints an error message.

Comment: @EzrealQ: In my answer, I made the assumption that you want to re-prompt the user if the input is invalid. However, if it would be sufficient for the program to simply print an error message and exit, then I could simplify the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use a conditional instruction like ("if"), but you need a value returned by the function fread() that you don't have because of the funcion structure that cuts off other char's. If your idea is to get input and save it, you should open two files with ("fopen("filename","mode")", the first in "r" mode and the second in "a" mode, and with a for loop with limit of 100 you substantially copy and paste the input from the first file to the second. hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the program to reject the input and print an error message if the input is too short, then the problem with the function `fread` is the following:

The function `fread` will not return until one of the following occurs:

1. It reads the desired number of characters.
2. It encounters end-of-file.
3. An error occurs.

There is no way to instruct `fread` to return as soon as it encounters a newline character.

Therefore, if you insist on using the function `fread`, then the only way to solve this problem would be to read one character at a time using `fread`, until you encounter a newline character. However, this is not meaningful.

If you want to read a single line of user input, then it is usually best to use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `fread`, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_DESIRED_CHARACTERS 35

//forward declaration
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size );

int main( void )
{
    char line[NUM_DESIRED_CHARACTERS+1];

    //loop until input is valid
    for (;;)
    {
        get_line_from_user( "Please enter a string: ", line, sizeof line );

        if ( strlen( line ) != NUM_DESIRED_CHARACTERS )
        {
            printf( "Input too short! It must be exactly %d characters!\n", NUM_DESIRED_CHARACTERS );
            continue;
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of loop
        break;
    }

    printf( "Input was successful.\nYou entered: %s\n", line );
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input from the
//user. It will remove the newline character, if it exists. If
//the line is too long to fit in the buffer, then the function
//will automatically reprompt the user for input. On failure,
//the function will never return, but will print an error
//message and call "exit" instead.
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char *p;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //attempt to find newline character
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small to store the entire line)
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            int c;

            //a missing newline character is ok if the next
            //character is a newline character or if we have
            //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
            //being piped from a file or if the user enters
            //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
            if ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
            {
                if ( ferror(stdin) )
                {
                    printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                printf( "Input was too long to fit in buffer!\n" );

                //discard remainder of line
                do
                {
                    c = getchar();

                    if ( ferror(stdin) )
                    {
                        printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }

                } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );

                //reprompt user for input by restarting loop
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character by overwriting it with
            //null character
            *p = '\0';
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter a string: This line is longer than 35 characters.
Input was too long to fit in buffer!
Please enter a string: This line is too short.
Input too short! It must be exactly 35 characters!
Please enter a string: This line is exactly 35 characters.
Input was successful.
You entered: This line is exactly 35 characters.
```

For demonstration purposes, I reduced `NUM_DESIRED_CHARACTERS` from `100` to `35`. If you want your program to take `100` characters of input instead of `35`, then you should change it back to `100`.

Comment: idk our prof wants that we use the fread function for reading and outputting the error ,thanks for help tho